# GetControllerName not being called in derived DefaultHttpControllerSelector implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, versioning

I'm attempting to do versioning with ASP.NET Web API.  I have created a simple controllerselector that derives from DefaultHttpControllerSelector.

```
public class MyHttpControllerSelector : DefaultHttpControllerSelector
{
    public MyHttpControllerSelector(HttpConfiguration config) : base(config) { }

    public override string GetControllerName(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return "SomeControllerName";
    }
}
```

In my WebApiConfig.Register:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new MyHttpControllerSelector(config));
```

My problem is GetControllerName is never called.  I may be misunderstanding the intent of this function, but I have seen plenty of examples, some right from Microsoft that use this method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I was not calling config.Routes.MapHttpRoute().  I was just using Attribute Routing.  Once I used MapHttpRoute() it seemed to start calling GetControllerName.